# Align a button at the down-right of an input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I want:

[image: wanted]

I tried [this approach](http://jsfiddle.net/GTTFY/) with no luck (gotten from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862668/align-right-side-of-button-and-input)). This is the unwanted result:

[image: current]

I guess it doesn't work because I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and span:

```
<div id=containerOfButtonAndInput class="container span12">
```

But how could I do it then?

Comment: Are you constrained to use only bootstrap classes?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CSS? Use something like this:

```
<div id="outer-container">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="label">Your Label<input id="input" /></div>
    <div style="height:10px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="button">Your Button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer-container{
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#eee;
}
#container{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
#label{
    float:right;
}
#button{
    float:right;
}
```

No magic here. Just regular formatting. Just don't be afraid of div-tags. Maybe you need more containers around your mask.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ahg5c/1/.